# Do I have to Install of git in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Is git already included in `VS2017` or do I need to install "Git for Windows"?

I know I can create a Git repository with a new application, but I am not sure whether it also allows the use of git commands from the GUI.

Comment: Easy to find out. Git can work local (a.o. Commit, Branch). Look in your Team Explorer and see what works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [Microsoft does suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/devops/develop/git/install-and-set-up-git) to [install Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), the same page ends with:

> Visual Studio offers a great out of the box Git experience without any additional tooling.
> Learn more in our [Visual Studio Git tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitworkflow?view=vsts).

So no, you don't need to install Git if you are using it through Visual Studio.

As mentioned in the [Git Pro Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Visual-Studio):

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013 Update 1, Visual Studio users have a Git client built directly into their IDE.

Comment: You need to install Git to run git from command line. Visual Studio 2019 will still not push an existing repo for example, so you will find those git commands useful.

Comment: @JasonHoningford I agree. I always install https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases in addition of Visual Studio.

Comment: Does the order of installation matter? That is, should one install GIT for Windows before Visual Studio?

Comment: @JayElston I believe VS should include its own Git installation. But having Git first is generally a good idea.